Interactions of the spin connection
I asked a similar question but since I didn't get my answer, I'll try to elaborate more. Within the context of quantum field theory in curved spacetime, one introduces a spin connection field $\omega_{\mu}^{ab}$ as a result of Lorentz invariance. So, my question is: does this spin connection field  interact with the other fields? For example, does it interact with the metric? What about the photon? So, here are some thoughts (which could be wrong):
For the photon, one can write the following Lagrangian:
$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$. In the definition of $F_{\mu\nu}$ one has terms like $\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}$ which when $\partial_{\mu}$ is changed to a covariant derivative $D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+i\omega_{\mu}^{ab}$, one would end up with interaction terms between $A_{\nu}$ and $\omega_{\mu}^{ab}$.
For the metric, one can be reminded that Christoffel symbols contain derivatives of the metric (terms like $\partial_{\lambda}g_{\mu\rho})$ which again by changing $\partial_{\lambda}$ to a covariant derivative $D_{\lambda}=\partial_{\lambda}+i\omega_{\lambda}^{ab}$, one would get interaction terms between $\omega_{\lambda}^{ab}$ and the metric $g_{\mu\rho}$.
So, are any of the above conclusions wrong? if so, why?

Intuitively, "spin connection" is a fancy term for Christoffel symbol. The spin connection is just the natural way of dealing with Christoffel symbols when you are working in a tetrad basis (for instance, when dealing with fermions).
As such, general relativity prescribes the spin connection is not an independent field. It is fully determined by the metric. You can extend this to more general gravitational theories in which the connection and the metric are treated independently (I think they are called metric-affine theories), but standard general relativity has the spin connection being completely determined by the metric (up to a choice of tetrad basis).
In other words, the degrees of freedom in the spin connection are the degrees of freedom of the gravitational field. The interactions you are looking for are the gravitational interaction.
Also, there are a few mistakes in your second and third paragraphs. Changing the derivative in the photon term doesn't affect anything: since $F_{\mu\nu}$ is defined in an antisymmetric combination, the contribution due to the spin connection vanishes. Also, the derivatives that go into the definition of the Christoffel symbols are not patched by the spin connection, they are only partial derivatives. The Christoffel symbols are equivalent to the spin connection.

Hi @Nickolas Alves, thanks for your response. There is one thing in your response that I don't understand: you say that changing the derivative in $F_{\mu\nu}$ doesn't change anything. I don't understand why. There are $\partial_{\mu}$  and $\partial_{\nu}$ in the definition of $F_{\mu\nu}$ . Changing these to covariant derivatives would give two ($\omega_{\mu}$ and $\omega_{\nu}$) spin connection fields which won't cancel. I can't see any cancelation in $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ either. Am I missing something?

@physics_2015 recall that for tensorial fields the spin connection should actually be written as the Christoffel symbol. Then write $F_{\mu\nu}$ in terms of $A_{\mu}$ and use the torsionless condition. $F_{\mu\nu} = \nabla_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \nabla_{\nu}A_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \Gamma^{\rho}{}{\mu\nu}A{\rho} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} + \Gamma^{\rho}{}{\nu\mu}A{\rho}  = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}.$ This is a simple argument, but the proper way of computing $F_{\mu\nu}$ is always equivalent to using partial derivatives, because the definition uses differential forms

The definition of $F$ is actually $F = dA$. From this expression it follows that you can always use partial derivatives to make the computation. You don't even need a metric

Hi @Nickolas Alves, a follow-up question came to my mind. I understand that for the metric theories of gravity, the spin connection is not an independent field and thus it doesn't interact with the photon. But what about those types of theories (metric-affine) which consider the spin connection as an independent field? Is it conceivable that in these theories the photon could interact with the spin connection?

@physics_2015 I don't know much about those theories, but in principle that makes sense to me. I don't see any obvious obstruction to such interactions

Thanks @Nickolas Alves, yes, that's what I was thinking but then I started to think that since spin connection has no electric charge, then the only way it can couple to photon would be through another type of charge. That's why I posted another question about the charge of the spin connection field. Let me know if you have any thoughts on this. Thanks.

@physics_2015 While the spin connection does not carry electric charge, the photon surely carries "gravitational charge", and thus would interact gravitationally with the connection (which is still part of gravitational phenomena)
